# How to make PWA icon fit for both Windows and macOS?

Tags: web, progressive-web-apps

I created the PWA icon for my web app following [Apple's app icon design template](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/#macos-apps).

It looks good on Dock of macOS, but looks a bit small on toollbar of Windows:

[image: icon on macOS]

[image: icon on Windows 11]

How can I make the icon fit for both platform? Or can I configure different icon for different platform?

Comment: I'm struggling with this as well. I wonder if you could dynamically generate the manifest.json file based on the user's operating system? A bit of a pain but maybe it would be doable.

Comment: I guess platforms have different preferred icon sizes?